# Do I have the right idea with using SetCapture() for a windowless checkbox?

Tags: winapi, checkbox, mousecapture

My Table control uses windowless checkboxes (because there can be an arbitrary number of checkboxes here). Right now, I use `TrackMouseEvent(TME_LEAVE)` and manually checking if the mouse is in the checkbox rect during a `WM_LBUTTONUP`. I have TODOs marked in my code for the edge cases that this causes, such as a missing `WM_LBUTTONUP` when the mouse has left the client area.

Now I notice [today's The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/02/25/10595729.aspx) says buttons use mouse captures. This got me thinking, and after looking into it, mouse captures would fit what I need more appropriately; **if my assumptions are correct** it would handle the various edge cases I mentioned above and be more correct in general.

In particular, the assumptions I make are: I should abandon any capture-related operations on a `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` even if every other condition is met. I will get a `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` after a `ReleaseCapture()`. After a `SetCapture()`, I will always end with either a `WM_LBUTTONUP` or a `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`, whichever comes first.

I've read both MSDN and a few articles I've found by Googling "setcapture correct use"; I just want to make sure I've got the right idea and will be implementing this correctly. Do I?

```
on WM_LBUTTONDOWN
    if the button is in a checkbox
        SetCapture()
        mark that we're in checkbox clicking mode
on WM_MOUSEMOVE
    if we are in checkbox clicking mode
        draw the checkbox in the pressed state
on WM_LBUTTONUP
    if we are in checkbox clicking mode
        leave checkbox clicking mode
        THEN call ReleaseCapture(), so we can ignore its WM_CAPTURECHANGED
        if the mouse was released in the same checkbox
            toggle it
on WM_CAPTURECHANGED
    if we are in checkbox clicking mode
        abandon checkbox clicking mode and leave the checkbox untoggled, even if the mouse is hovering over the checkbox
```

Do I have the right idea here? And in particular, is my order of operations for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have said is basically right, although a real checkbox tracks `WM_MOUSEMOVE` while in "clicking mode" and displays the checkbox in its original state if the mouse moves off of it. So to emulate that you should have:

```
on WM_MOUSEMOVE
    if we are in checkbox clicking mode
        if mouse is over the checkbox
            draw the checkbox in the pressed (toggled) state
        else
            draw the checkbox in the original state
```

Comment: Thanks. And I don't call `ReleaseCapture()` in `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` itself, right? (Forgot this the first time.)

Comment: No, if you get `WM_CAPTURECHANGED` you've already lost the capture, so no need to release it again.

Comment: All right. I've now implemented `SetCapture()` and everything works fine. Thanks again!